# How to save that

Tags: haskell

I am self learning haskell from [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions). I do not understand anything when the author says "Save this as baby.hs". What I have to save and how I can save that?

Comment: He simply means for you to save the Haskell code in the box in a file that you should name "baby.hs"

Comment: Yeah as Sarah said, and make sure you put all files as the file type (as the extension is being specified I'm assuming it doesn't choose this type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open your favorite text editor
2. Type: doubleMe x = x + x
3. save the file as baby.hs
4. go to the directory where you saved the file and launch ghci
5. type: :l baby

Comment: Thank you for that.My lack of patience in reading it is probably reflected by the downvote.